# Jquery animate(), preventing animation

Tags: jquery

As part of a call to the `jQuery` `animate` function, sometimes I want to prevent the animation. Is there a way, as part of the `animate` function, to prevent the animation? Such as with a `before` property?

I would like to do something like this:

```
$('#myMovingDiv').animate(
{
    before: // RUN A FUNCTION, IF FUNCTION RETURNS TRUE, CANCEL ANIMATION
    left: '+=100'
}
, 1000, function(){});
```

To address the comments below, I cannot just do an `if` before the animate, because the animate changes the value of the `if`, and if the animate is not complete, the `if` condition is not met.
Example -

```
//THIS WILL NOT WORK IF ANIMATION IS NOT FINISHED BEFORE 2ND CLICK
$("#myClickableDiv").click(function () {
    if (document.getElementById(myMovingDiv').offsetLeft == 0) {

       $('#myMovingDiv').animate({
           left: '+=850'
       }, 400, function () {
        // Animation complete.
       });

    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you are trying to do.  If it is a matter of preventing the property from being animated, in this case `left`, then you could use jQuery animate's  [`step function`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step).

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('#myMovingDiv').animate({
            left: '+=100'
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                if(parseInt(now) > 20){
                    $(this).stop(); 
                    fx.end = fx.start; //prevents div from moving
                }
            }
        },
        1000);
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/qhzVm/3/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible like that, but you can develop a solution using `.filter()`

```
$('#myMovingDiv').filter(function(idx, el){
    return true;// or false based on condition
}).animate({
     left: '+=100'
 }, 1000, function () {});
```

Or why don't you put an if condition before the animate method is called

```
if(condition){
    $('#myMovingDiv').animate({
         left: '+=100'
     }, 1000, function () {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, but this still has the same problem as I mention in my question. (I have added additional information). Multiple clicks before the animation is complete, causes this not to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a strange resquest since you can just do an `if`, but if you absolutly want a `before` option, put this script somewhere in you code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.oldAnim = $.fn.animate;
    $.fn.animate = function(){
        var args = arguments;
        if(typeof args[1] == 'object'){
            if(args[1].before){
                var callBefore = args[1].before().apply(this);
                if(callBefore || callBefore == undefined){
                    return this.oldAnim.apply(this, args);
                }else{
                    return this;
                }
            }
        }
        return this.oldAnim.apply(this, args);
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Then you will have a `before` option. Returning false, 0, null or empty string will cancel the animation. However, returning undefined will trigger the animation.

You can call it like that :

```
$('selector').animate({'hegit' : 'value'}, {before : function(){}, complete : function(){} /*etc, etc*/})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cWC5B/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Karl-Andre, your code is giving me an error though - Object #<error> has no method 'apply'